# replace escaped characters with characters surrounded by quotes

Tags: regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to search-replace through a string that may contain any number of characters preceded by a backslash, and produce the same string but with backslash removed, and those characters surrounded by single quotes.

E.g.:
`ab c\d\e fg \h ij`

Should produce
`ab c'de' fg 'h' ij`

Is it possible to do this with a single preg_replace?

Comment: i think it's backslash.

Comment: Sorry @AvinashRaj, I'm not following you at all... Where should the backslash go in this context?

Comment: `any number of characters preceded by a backspace`, could you explain what the backspace is?

Comment: Ooop! My mistake! You are right, backslah. Sorry about that.

Comment: What would be your expected output for this `foo\bar\g` input?

Comment: `foo'b'ar'g'`
And `foo\b\ar\g` should produce `foo'ba'r'g'`

Comment: No @chris85, it's not just replacing `\.` by `'.'`. A sequence of 'escaped' characters should have its backslashes removed, and then be surrounded by single quotes.

Comment: Yup, got it after your example thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with `preg_replace` *(because you have to deal with an unknow number of repetitions)*, you must use `preg_replace_callback` to find all the sequence. Then the callback function removes the backslashes and returns the result between quotes:

```
$str='ab c\d\e fg \h ij';

echo preg_replace_callback('~(?:\\\.)+~', function ($m) {
    return "'". str_replace('\\', '', $m[0]) . "'";
}, $str);
```

Comment: Why the three backslashes here `(?:\\\.)`? Shouldn't two be enough? The third one seems to be escaping the `.`

Comment: @yivi: Not in a pattern! You need two backslahes to obtain a literal backslash in a single quoted string and one more to obtain a literal backslash for the pattern. Note that with a double quoted string, you need four backslashes but only two if you use the nowdoc syntax.